# How can I reliably tell when an AWS RDS modification operation is complete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

I'm using `boto3` in a small script to change the master credentials of an RDS cluster.

The issue is that the RDS cluster status from `describe_db_clusters` isn't reliably up to date. After I issue a `modify_db_cluster` (specifically, I'm updating the master password), there is a high chance that `describe_db_clusters` shows that the cluster is still "available", before it enters the "modifying" state.

The sequence of events:

1. cluster is available
2. modify cluster password
3. cluster is still available
4. cluster is modifying
5. cluster is available (operation complete)

The issue is that I can't reliably tell between states 3 and 5.

Notes:

- I'm using `ApplyImmediately=True` for the master password update
- I see the same problematic behaviour, whether I inspect the cluster status, or the cluster's `PendingModifiedValues`

The docs do mention this for `describe_db_instances`:

> MasterUserPassword (string) --
> The new password for the master user. The password can include any printable ASCII character except "/", """, or "@".
> Changing this parameter doesn't result in an outage and the change is asynchronously applied as soon as possible. **Between the time of the request and the completion of the request, the MasterUserPassword element exists in the PendingModifiedValues element of the operation response.**

However, that footnote doesn't exist for `describe_db_clusters`.

How can I *reliably* know when my modification operation is complete?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, only if there is a pending change, `PendingModifiedValues` will be present in `describe_db_clusters` response:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import boto3
import time
import datetime
client = boto3.client('rds',region_name='ap-southeast-2')
while True:
    response = client.describe_db_clusters(
            Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'db-cluster-id',
                'Values': [
                    'database-1',
                ]
            }
        ]
    )
    for cluster in response['DBClusters']:
        print(cluster['DBClusterIdentifier'],cluster['Status'])
        if "PendingModifiedValues" in cluster:
            print(cluster['PendingModifiedValues'])
        else:
            print('No PendingModifiedValues in response')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
$ ./check_rds_cluster.py 

database-1 available
No PendingModifiedValues in response
2021-03-28 13:19:45
database-1 available
No PendingModifiedValues in response
2021-03-28 13:19:46
database-1 available
No PendingModifiedValues in response
2021-03-28 13:19:48
database-1 available
{'MasterUserPassword': '****'}
2021-03-28 13:19:49
...
database-1 available
{'MasterUserPassword': '****'}
2021-03-28 13:19:53
database-1 available
{'MasterUserPassword': '****'}
2021-03-28 13:19:55
database-1 resetting-master-credentials
{'MasterUserPassword': '****'}
2021-03-28 13:19:56
database-1 resetting-master-credentials
{'MasterUserPassword': '****'}
...
2021-03-28 13:21:17
database-1 available
No PendingModifiedValues in response
2021-03-28 13:21:18
database-1 available
No PendingModifiedValues in response
2021-03-28 13:21:19
```

It is documented in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DBCluster.html:

> **PendingModifiedValues**
>
> A value that specifies that changes to the DB
> cluster are pending. This element is only included when changes are
> pending. Specific changes are identified by subelements.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, unfortunately. The issue I'm observing is that `PendingModifiedValues` *doesn't* appear immediately after I request the password to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you could create a **waiter** function in your code. The boto3 RDS provides a couple of [waiters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#waiters) already, but none applies to a cluster. The closest is [DBInstanceAvailable](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Waiter.DBInstanceAvailable).

Basically, a waiter is a function that **pulls AWS API iteratively** with 15 seconds delays to check if a given resource is in a desired state, e.g. RDS instance has been created and is available for use.

So you could **create your own waiter** which would pull `describe_db_clusters` ever 10 or 15 seconds until `PendingModifiedValues` is gone from the response or has some other state of interest. Maybe checking `DBClusters`'s `Status` is enough.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, unfortunately. A waiter would be subject to the same issue of the `PendingModifiedValues` not appearing until after a delay.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.

```
while self.get_db_cluster_status() == "available":
    time.sleep(5)
    logging.getLogger().info(
        f"waiting for cluster change to begin '{self.cluster_name}'"
    )
waiter = self.rds.get_waiter("db_cluster_available")
waiter.wait(DBClusterIdentifier=self.cluster_name)
```

EDIT: the `get_db_cluster_status()` function

```
def get_db_cluster_status(self) -> str:
    """
    Return the status of the current rds cluster.
    """
    resp = self.rds.describe_db_clusters(
        DBClusterIdentifier=self.cluster_name,
    )

    # It's okay to use index [0] here because we're requesting one specific
    # cluster only, and cluster names are unique within the given region.
    status = resp["DBClusters"][0]["Status"]

    return status
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).